# Show coverage in github

Tags: python, github-actions, code-coverage, codecov

I have a python project in github, and I want that with every push, github shows the coverage of the project. Is that possible? Which tool do I need? When I used to work with java, jacoco solves this, but in python I don't know what tool I can use.
My .github/workflows/github-actions.yaml is that:

```
name: Python CI
on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up Python
      uses: actions/setup-python@v4
      with:
        python-version: '3.11'
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pip install pytest pytest-cov
        pytest tests/
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

It is definetaly possible. One of the possible solution is to use [codecov.io](https://codecov.io) service that provides functionality you need.

In order to to that you need to make the following steps:

#### Sign up and get Codecov token

First, you need to create an account in codecov.io service and then get the API token by going through Profile picture -> Settings -> Settings tag -> Access pane -> "Generate token" button.

Give a name for token and click another "Generate token" button.

Finally, copy your token.

#### Add a codecov token in Github secrets

Once, you have your token, you need to securely provide it to CI/CD pipelines. In order to do this, you need to access setings page of your repository navigate to "Secrets and variables" -> "Actions" and select "New repository secret". You can consider adding organisation-wide secret if you're going to use one token for multiple repositories in your organization.

Set the name, I personally prefer "CODECOV_TOKEN", and paste token you've got from previous step.

#### Update your Github action

Finally, you need to amend your github action in order to start upload coverage reports to the codecov.io.

##### Update "Test with pytest" step

```yaml
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pip install pytest pytest-cov
        pytest --cov=./ --cov-report=xml tests/
```

NOTE: `--cov=./ --cov-report=xml` parameters added to the `pytest` command in order to instruct `pytest-cov` library to collect coverage and provide it in xml format.

##### Add "Collect coverage" step

```yaml
   - name: Collect coverage
      uses: codecov/codecov-action@v3
      with:
        token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
        fail_ci_if_error: true
        files: ./coverage.xml
        verbose: true
```

This is official Github action of Codecov service. It should be a good baseline that allows you to check how it works.

NOTE: `token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}` where you need to provide a token, so it may differs if you will give it another name.

I hope this helps you get everything set up. I encourage you to read more about configuration options codecov provides in order to tune the integration.